# Create an Arraylist from a String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to create a mini-description of people. When doing this, I want 23 characters on each line, and then add that bit to the ArrayList. However I don't want it to split words.

Instead of

```
- Hello there I am Al
- ex and I like blueb
- erries and I always
- wear sandals and ea
- t fish. I like to s
- mell flowers
```

It will skip to the next space before adding it to the list:

```
- Hello there I am Alex
- and I like blueberries
- and I wear sandals and
- eat fish. I like to
- smell flowers.
```

Here a sample of my code which doesn't actually do anything yet:

```
public List<String> getDescription(String lore) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();


    return l;
}
```

I tried to do a StringBuilder but got stuck, because I coundn't reset the for loop:

```
public List<String> getDescription(String lore) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp = lore;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        if ((lore.charAt(i) == ' ') && i > 20) {
            l.add(sb.toString());
            temp = temp.substring(sb.length());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }

        sb.append(temp.charAt(i));
    }

    return l;
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of input and output. This question is worded confusingly.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your elements you want to add to the `ArrayList` are separated with a space in your string:

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList(tmp.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset "for" loop this way:

```
    ...
    l.add(sb.toString());
    temp = temp.substring(sb.length());
    i = 0;
    sb.setLength(0);
    ...
```